# Laravel user login continue with same cart

Tags: laravel

I am implementing this shipping cart for laravel (https://github.com/darryldecode/laravelshoppingcart/issues/250). When a user logs in I would like to continue their cart, for this to happen I would need to save the session id then merge that data on login.

The problem I am having is that when i flash the cart inside `\app\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController.php`, the session id changes.  It seems that all files inside `Auth` changes when `getId()`.

```
session()->flash('guest_cart', [
    'session' => session()->getId(),
    'data' => cart()->getContent()
]);
```

So if I flash the session else where, how do I merge it into the new user cart on `login` if I am not able to retrieve the the original `getId()`?

When I output `dd(session()->all());` inside `LoginController` it shows an empty array.  I would somehow need to capture `session('guest_cart.data');` during login.

I tried adding this to `LoginController.php`

```
protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user){
    if(Auth::check()){

        $session_id = \Session::getId();
        $cartObj = \Cart::session($session_id)->getContent();

          if (\Auth::guest()) {
              session()->flash('guest_cart', [
                  'session' => $session_id,
                  'data' => $cartObj
              ]);
          }


        dd(session()->all());   
    }
```

but again `guest_cart` returns an empty array because `$session_id = \Session::getId();` has changed.

Comment: session id is created with new session, every login creates a new session so the old data will be flushed out, so you need to calculate the cart details of the current user & store it to session everytime, you can create a event that everytime a user logs in the cart details are stored in the session

Comment: @bhucho thank you for the response,  where would I create an event to retrieve during login?  Can you point me towards a direction on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

> where would I create an event to retrieve during login? Can you point me towards a direction on how to accomplish this?

We can just override the `authenticated()` method in `Auth\LoginController.php` to save anything to the session. If you want to store only few values then just update it.

`authenticated()` method is called just after the user is logged in & it is defined empty in the trait `AuthenticatesUsers` used in LoginController.

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request; 

protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
    {
        if(Auth::check){
            //assuming that you have a cart relationship with user.
            $cartData = Auth::user()->cart()->getContent();
            $request->session()->put('cart_data', $cartData);

        }
        
        return redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath());
    }
```

If you have a lot of things to do you can then create an event, then use listeners to listen to that event. We will call the event from authenticated method itself.

Comment: you can use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65048507/9471283) as reference how I have used authenticated method

Comment: @bhuncho im getting an error `Access to undeclared static property: Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth::$user `.  I tried adding  code in `authenticated()`, revised answer above.

Comment: spell mistake to add `()`, it should be `Auth::user()`

Comment: In the code above you are trying to access sessions of Auth::guest(), but session is created for a loggedin user, guest means it is a non logged user, also if you flash it will be available for one redirect, you need to put in the session

Comment: session id will change with each session even if you store it in db for each login by a user the sessionid will be different

Comment: store the cart id/ids of the logged in user & when user clicks on view cart or something like that show carts for those cart id/ids stored in session

Comment: The user is a guest first with cart items based on their sessionId, during login I am trying to capture that guest cart but I cannot because the sessionId changes.

Comment: what you are trying to obtain is cached data not data stored in session used the cached data of the guest user, make them login & use the same cached data after login to show their cart, You will never be able to achieve this behaviour using sessions

Comment: I see, I will look into user `cache` then.  current code gives error `Call to undefined method App\User::cart() `

Comment: It will not work I have given an example that assuming if you have a cart relationship with users